# LDAP Auth proxy adding headers according to LDAP groups

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, single-sign-on, mod-auth-kerb

I'm trying to setup some WebSSO mechanisms, that allow my customer to authenticate people against internal Active Directory and then add secure (https) headers containing credential information.

### Version 1 OK : authenticate and adding headers

The first version is "quite" simple. I'm using Apache and mod_auth_kerb to autenticate, and then I add headers. The following configuration is a kinsnippet of existing one.

```
<VirtualHost  *:80>
    ServerName external-sso.corp.fr
    RewriteEngine On
</VirtualHost>

<location /app2> 
    # Authentication
    AuthType Kerberos
    AuthName "Active Directory Authentication"
    KrbMethodNegotiate On
    KrbMethodK5Passwd On
    KrbLocalUserMapping On
    KrbAuthRealms CORP.REALM.FR
    Krb5KeyTab /etc/krb5/http-myserver.corp.realm.fr.keytab
    Require valid-user

    # Identification
    AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://corp.realm.fr:636/DC=realm,DC=corp,DC=fr?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=App2,OU=cloud,OU=prod,OU=Authentication,DC=realm,DC=corp,DC=fr"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "*******"
    AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on
    Require valid-user

    # Adding Information into headers
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} (.+)
    RewriteRule .* - [E=RU:%{REMOTE_USER}]
    RequestHeader set X-App2-Remote-User %{RU}e
</location>
```

### Version 2 no idea ! : authenticate and adding headers according to groups

Into the next version, I would like to add specific headers ONLY if the user belongs to a group, e.g. user account name if he is allowed to access to APP2, generic account if not.

**I don't know how to achieve that, even creating two different vhosts ...**, even if it's possible.

Could you please give me some hints ? Don't hesitate to add advises, even I know that :

- Active Directoy already have web-sso mechanisms with AD/AM
- Adding headers is not really secured (no matter here, using HTTPS and IP filtering)
- I really need a full web-sso (we are actually comparing Shibboleth, AD/AM and other solutions but don't have time to wait :) ... you know, business is business !

Answer (score 1):

Would [require-group](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#reqgroup) instead of require-user help?

Also see [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/269344/how-to-authenticate-users-in-nested-groups-in-apache-ldap) about nested group enumeration.

```
Require ldap-filter memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=Access to Apache,OU=My Organization Unit,DC=company,DC=com
```

Comment: Those links are interesting, because they provide me a way to apply many filters. But this don't help to realize different actions according to the groups users belong to. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using LDAP, you can avoid mod_rewrite. Though setting:

```
AuthLDAPRemoteUserAttribute sAMAccountName
```

had no effect for me with Apache-2.4 -- contrary to the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#authldapremoteuserattribute) -- what did work, was `%{AUTHENTICATE_sAMAccountName}e`. For example:

```
RequestHeader  set X-App2-Remote-User %{AUTHENTICATE_sAMAccountName}e
```

Note, that the `AuthLDAPURL` needs to contain `?sAMAccountName` at the end for `AUTHENTICATE_sAMAccountName` to be created in the environment by mod_ldap. You already have it in your example.

Comment: Since I no longer work for this company, I won't be able anymore to test your solution, but tanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my issue modifying the way I gave the problem.

I managed to have 2 different application contexts (eg /app2-anonymous and /app2-nameduser) called by the fist application (app1).

But I'm still looking for a better answer, even if seems that my solution is "the Apache HTTP way".