# Apache LDAP Authentication with AD Subgroup

Tags: active-directory, ldap, authentication, apache-2.4

I am trying to authenticate using an Active Directory User on a Website running on Apache.

**My Setup**

*Active Directory:* User "steven" is a member of the group "staff". User "cindy" is a member of the group "finances" which is a member of "staff" (= cindy is a member of a subgroup of the "staff" group).

*Apache:* Apache 2.4 with mod_authnz_ldap

*My Apache site config:*

```
AuthName "Please enter your login data."

AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider ldap

AuthLDAPBindDN account@domain.local
AuthLDAPBindPassword "userpassword"

AuthLDAPURL "ldap://dc.domain.local/DC=domain,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"

Require ldap-group CN=Staff,OU=Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=local
```

**Problem**

Steven (or any other user that would be a direct member of the "staff" group) authenticates successfully, however members of sub groups, such as cindy will not authenticate.

I have already tried adding "AuthLDAPMaxSubGroupDepth 10" (10 should be the default value anyway) but that did not help either.

Anyone who might be able to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't had occasion to use the `AuthLDAPMaxSubGroupDepth` directive. I've always used the [LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN](https://serverfault.com/a/424706/7200) search control instead. You might have a look at that. It should perform better, in terms of network traffic between the DC and Apache, because the DC itself will resolve the nested groups.